# German Job seeking visa, Should I request a Diploma recognition?

Tags: working-visas, germany

I'm preparing my request for a job seeking visa, and as the email of the embassy state :

> 7.Deutscher Hochschulabschluss oder anerkannter ausländischer, einem deutschen vergleichbarer Hochschulabschluss

I have a Master degree from a university that is referenced in the Anabin database as H+, now I'm wondering if I should request a paid equivalence for my specific Master degree? There are over 20 branches at the university and only 4 are listed in the sub list (A4).